# "join: file 2 is not in sorted order" only when writing to file

Tags: bash, shell, join

I hade to join two files where some processing is done on 2nd file on-the-fly (sorting, removing first row), then some processing is done on the resulting file and it is finally written on disk.

```
join HM3.tmp.snps <(sort <( sed '1d' sumstats/PASS_BMI1.sumstats)) | awk 'BEGIN{print("SNP\tN\tZ\tA1\tA2")}; {print $0}' | tr " " "\t"  > hm3_sumstats/PASS_BMI1.sumstats
```

I get the error "join: file 2 is not in sorted order". 
The weird thing is that this error doesn't appear if I don't write the result to disk, so

```
join HM3.tmp.snps <(sort <( sed '1d' sumstats/PASS_BMI1.sumstats)) | awk 'BEGIN{print("SNP\tN\tZ\tA1\tA2")}; {print $0}' | tr " " "\t"
```

seems to work and print the result in std output.

Note that file1 is already sorted.

How can I make this work and why does the error depend on whether I print the result on a file?

Thanks

Comment: I actually realized that the file gets written anyways, but I am not sure if some lines are missing since I get the error

Comment: I found that problem is the same if I pre-sort the file2 and call join on the two files. I get the same error but the file is written apparently with no problems

Comment: If you sort the pre-sorted file2 again, do you get the same contents? I wonder if sort might be having problems when given an arg that's a pipe or socket (whatever /dev/fd/nnn is on your system) that's the result of using `<()`.